# Rails throwing Unpermitted parameters: name error when using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am trying to follow this as an example: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise/

I made a project of my own where I try it out and everything is working fine exept for the name part. If I try to make a new user or edit it, rails will throw this `Unpermitted parameters: name` error.

I have added name as a string into the users table and everything should be fine. I read that some people suggested adding a specific user_params mathod to allow :name but the example I linked before does not have it and in there it all works.

Also worth noting maybe that a direct `INSERT INTO` in pgAdmin will insert a new row with a name without any problems. So it's something with Rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Unpermitted parameters" means you're doing mass assignment without marking the passed in parameter as permitted. Have another look at this section of the example app documentation: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise/#adding-a-name-attribute. Make sure the `name` attribute is listed in *config/initializers/devise_permitted_parameters.rb*.

Comment: Thanks! Works. That is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer to resolve the question.